# <REDACTED> Error in BigQuery project history tab while submitting google datastream job

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-datastream

I'm submitting a Datastream job that reads from Aurora PostgreSQL and writes to a BigQuery dataset and table. The Datastream job seems to be completed and ingest data in bigQuery dataset correctly, But i am getting Below error in PROJECT HISTORY TAB.

It is a CDC job so i am not sure the CDC is injesting in BigQuery or not. Please help me on this issue.

Error Message:

Invalid job ID "". Job IDs must be alphanumeric (plus underscores and dashes) and must be at most 1024 characters long.

[image]

Comment: You can find more details about this error by clicking the [job id](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-jobs#view_job_details_2).Let me know if this helps you or not?

Comment: @kiranmathew Thank you for the response . Found the issue and fixed it . It was some permission issue in BigQuery.

Comment: Glad to hear that your issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the issue : The Error  is because I don't have certain permissions to view the Project History logs in BigQuery .

Once BigQuery Resource Viewer permission provided to my id from then I can able to see the logs without error.